# android sensors with GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, sensors

I have main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static SensorManager sensorService;
  private GLSurfaceView view;
  private Sensor sensor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        view.setRenderer(new SceneView());
        setContentView(view);

        sensorService = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorService.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
        if (sensor != null) {
            sensorService.registerListener(mySensorEventListener, sensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            Log.i("Compass MainActivity", "Registerered for ORIENTATION Sensor");

        } else {
            Log.e("Compass MainActivity", "Registerered for ORIENTATION Sensor");
            Toast.makeText(this, "ORIENTATION Sensor not found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }


    private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // angle between the magnetic north directio
            // 0=North, 90=East, 180=South, 270=West
            float azimuth = event.values[0];
            view.updateData(azimuth);

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (sensor != null) {
            sensorService.unregisterListener(mySensorEventListener);
        }
    }

}
```

and

Scene

```
public class SceneView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private float position = 0;
    private Square mSquare;

    public SceneView() {
        mSquare = new Square();
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -6);
        mSquare.draw(gl);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void updateData(float position) {
    }

}
```

When I call `updateData` I get error because `view` is null in `SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener` How to solve this?

In http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html author use `extends View` and him code works perfectly, and when I use `implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer` with different constructor procedure all breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your `GLSurfaceView` again in your `onCreate` method as a *local* variable:

```
GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
```

So when refering it in `onCreate`, it doesn't refer to the *member GLSurfaceView* (`private GLSurfaceView view`), but to the *local* one.

Omit the declaration of `view` in `onCreate`:

```
view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
```

And it will work.

Comment: I change declaration to `private GLSurfaceView view;` also I write in onCreate `view = new GLSurfaceView(this);` Now I get `cannot find symbol method updateData(float)`. What I do wrong?

Comment: The method `updateData` belongs to the type `SceneView`, not `GLSurfaceView`. Keep a reference to the `SceneView` you passed as a renderer to the `GLSurfaceView` and use it to call `updateData`.